# <textbox> display the end of the text section when i add input Zk framework

Tags: java, text, view, zk

I using ZK framework to code front end and i have a problem.

When i add an input (The input is a output of other events) is a long text in "text box" component, the "text box" display the end of the text.

Example: when i add a text like: "There are many ways to judge a city's success as a tourist destination beyond the number of visitors it gets.",
the text box will display the end of the text ".... number of visitors it gets.", i want the "text box" display the head of the text "There are many ways to judge...".

How can i fix it, thank you guys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I simulate your case with https://zkfiddle.org/sample/81hu59/1-display-text

But when I `setValue()`, the textbox always shows the beginning of the input text. Only when I call `setSelectionRange()`, it will display the end of the input text. Do you call that method?

If not, please show me your case with [zkfiddle](https://zkfiddle.org) or related code.

Comment: You are right, I have called the same method as Setelectionrange (); But to display the text i using component value = "@load(variable)" , to load the value from the variable when the variable change when i call the method() by using onClick="@command('setSelectionRange(20, 20)')". Do this describe can help you a little bit, i will try to simulate the case by using the zkfiddle. I'am the newbie so it will take a time, and i sorry about my english, i know it hard to read, thank you because spend your time to reply my question

Comment: if you don't want to show the end of the text, then don't call `setSelectionRange(20, 20)` which will select and show the text at index 20.

Comment: Describe a technical question in English sometimes mislead readers since most of us are not native-speaker. That's why the community bot suggest you providing enouch code which demonstrate your question better than what you describe.